# Delphi Datasnap - How to customize JSON marshalling

Tags: json, delphi, marshalling, datasnap, delphi-10.1-berlin

In my Delphi 10.1 Berlin Datasnap REST application, I need to customize the JSON serializaton of an object.

I would like to find a solution that makes use of the JSONReflect attribute, and doesn't involve the creation of Converters and Reverters for every specific field, as described in [this article](http://www.danieleteti.it/custom-marshallingunmarshalling-in-delphi-2010/) by Daniele Teti.

In particular, I'm trying to serialize an object that contains:

- a binary file, to convert in JSON representation - like a byte array
- some TDateTime fields, to convert in a String with ISO format

I have found a [technical PDF document](https://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/rest-servers-in-delphi-xe-using-datasnap.pdf) by Marco Cantù, that talks about JSONReflect attribute to enable conversion of fields, but I cannot find documentation about it.

Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use of JSONReflect attribute automatically implies use of converters and reverters. Delphi XE6 ships with sample project MarshallUnmarshall where JSON serialization is covered. RAD Studio Demo Code is also available [online](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE6/Object%20Pascal/DataSnap/).

If you want to serialize an object that contains a TDateTime field in a string with ISO format, you can also use standard Tjson class defined in Rest.Json unit. It contains an [ObjectToJsonString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/REST.Json.TJson.ObjectToJsonString) method. In the AOptions parameter you can specify to format dates using ISO standard.

```
class function ObjectToJsonString(AObject: TObject; AOptions: TJsonOptions = [joDateIsUTC, joDateFormatISO8601]): string;
```

To serialize a binary file in JSON Daniele Teti has sample code in his [Delphi Cookbook](http://www.danieleteti.it/delphi-cookbook/). Unfortunately I can not share sample code I think. Recommended reading! [Second edition](http://www.danieleteti.it/delphi-cookbook-2nd-edition/) has just appeared.